# How to write a Nginx module?

Tags: nginx, plugins, nginx-module

I'm trying to find tutorials on how to build a module/plugin for Nginx web server.

Can someone help please, I just can't seem to find the appropriate tutorials.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Quoting from the documentation:

> Evan Miller has written the definitive [guide to Nginx module development](http://www.evanmiller.org/nginx-modules-guide.html). 
>   But some parts of it are a little out of date. You've been warned.
>
> A github search turned up the [Nginx Development Kit](https://github.com/simpl/ngx_devel_kit). It seems to be
>   more up to date.

From my own personal experience, [Evan Miller's guide](http://www.evanmiller.org/nginx-modules-guide.html) was of a great help. You must also have a deep understanding of how NGINX works. [Agentzh's tutorial](http://openresty.org/download/agentzh-nginx-tutorials-en.html) can help you.

Reading the source code of [his modules](https://github.com/agentzh) is always helpful too.

There is also a [video tutorial](http://www.airpair.com/nginx/extending-nginx-tutorial) that I haven't check yet, but it seems nice.

Answer (score 16):

http://www.evanmiller.org/nginx-modules-guide.html

> Nginx has a **module chain**. When Nginx needs to gzip or chunk-encode a response, it whips out a module to do the work. When Nginx blocks access to a resource based on IP address or HTTP auth credentials, a module does the deflecting. When Nginx communicates with Memcache or FastCGI servers, a module is the walkie-talkie...
>
> The purpose of this guide is to teach you the details of Nginx's module chain... When you're done with the guide, you'll be able to design and produce high-quality modules that enable Nginx to do things it couldn't do before. Nginx's module system has a lot of nuance and nitty-gritty, so you'll probably want to refer back to this document often. I have tried to make the concepts as clear as possible, but I'll be blunt, writing Nginx modules can still be hard work...

Comment: have you made any progress on that? I'm kind of in the same situation here. Take a look at my post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204812/nginx-module-development-with-mysql-posible

Comment: The bit I felt wasn't as explicit as it should be in an otherwise fantastic post was this: 'Finally, add a module directive to nginx's configuration (default is /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf) to enable the module for a location.
location = /hello {
  hello_world;
}'

Answer (score 3):

You can find an official [nginx development guide here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/dev/development_guide.html).

The end of the document leads to a new repo (6 weeks before this post) full of [examples here](http://hg.nginx.org/nginx-dev-examples?_ga=2.259695626.1427277853.1515363665-1058918063.1515363665).