# How does nginx_redis2_module achieve non-blocking operation?

Tags: nginx, openresty

I need a nginx server that receives HTTP request and sends back response from Redis-store and this should be non-blocking. After Googling and going through forums, i came across the nginx_redis2_module. I tried going through the code but was not able to understand how it works. How have they achieved non-blocking operation? Have they achieved this by adding events to nginx's event loop ? Is there any document or sample code how this is done ?

source : https://github.com/openresty/redis2-nginx-module

Answer (score 1):

The essence of nginx is non blocking modules.
It is complex area.
Here you may found some starting points: [how to write Nginx module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187314/how-to-write-nginx-module/21499329#21499329)

FYI:

> When used in conjunction with lua-nginx-module, it is recommended to
>   use the lua-resty-redis library instead of this module though, because
>   the former is much more flexible and memory-efficient.

Comment: i know how to write basic nginx module, in fact i have even written a redis module, but it is not non-blocking. I want a non-blocking one. I have seen the 'lua_nginx_module' and the 'nginx_redis2_module' as well. Want to know how they work, i.e how they achieve non-blocking operations.

Comment: A big picture - you issue a subrequest and nginx returns control to your module and request context upon response, then you may create response for origimal request http://www.evanmiller.org/nginx-modules-guide-advanced.html#subrequests

Comment: i searched nginx_redis2_module code in github, couldn't find anything related to sub-requests

Comment: To be more precise - nginx_redis2_module is upstream handler http://www.evanmiller.org/nginx-modules-guide.html#proxying. The key sentence -  <It merely sets callbacks that will be invoked when the upstream server is ready to be written to and read from>